# UWP Launching Sim Application

Tags: c#, uwp, sim-toolkit

MS [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/network/reserved-uri-to-launch-sim-toolkit) said I can launch Sim application using this code:

```
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync("ms-settings-uicctoolkit:");
```

When I run this on my phone which has `2 SIM`, it will display the first `SIM` application menu, how to launch my secondary `SIM` application?